# json.Unmarshal not poupulating the struct while doing a curl call

Tags: go

i am trying to populate the struct and do some further operations, my fields in struct are exported but the value is not getting populated when i do a curl.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Y struct {
    Name      string   `json:"name"`
    EventType []string `json:"eventType"`
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/config/export/eventtypes", eventTypes).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/config/export/ia/outputs", createEventList).Methods("POST")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
}

func eventTypes(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var resp []map[string]string
    x := make(map[string]string)
    x["name"] = "HTTP"
    x["description"] = "http"
    resp = append(resp, x)
    x1 := make(map[string]string)
    x1["name"] = "KRB"
    x1["description"] = "http"
    resp = append(resp, x1)
    x2 := make(map[string]string)
    x2["name"] = "FileINFO"
    x2["description"] = "http"
    resp = append(resp, x2)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
}

func createEventList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var s Y
    x, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    log.Printf("%v", string(x))
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(x), &s)
    log.Printf("%+v", s)

}
```

i am testing this with `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8000/config/export/ia/outputs -d'{"name":"test","eventType":"["http","dmtp"]"}'` and my output is `{ []}`
but the same thing when i try with python code

```
    myobj = {"name":"test","eventType":test}

y= requests.post("http://localhost:8000/config/export/ia/outputs",json=myobj)
```

prints `{Name:test EventType:[HTTP KRB FileINFO]}`

Comment: `ioutil.ReadAll` and `json.Unmarshal` both return errors. Don't ignore them. Add show the actual contents of `body`. And why does your `json` have quotes around the `eventType` array?

Comment: oh yea, that did it, quotes around eventType was a mistake, small detail missed.Thanks @Marc

Comment: You have an extra quote before and after the square brackets. As Marc said, don't ignore errors, *especially* if something you don't understand happens.

Comment: General Go suggestion: never ignore errors. Always check them and at least log/print them, so you know what is going on. In this case it would have thrown a json parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the quotes for array in your curl request